# TypeScript Object Possibly undefined if check is not performed on the same line

Tags: typescript

Take a look at these two examples:

```
// Example 1
const realm = process.env.REALM;
const hasRealm = realm && ServiceClient.realms.includes(realm);
const subDomain = realm && ServiceClient.realms.includes(realm) ? `.${realm.toLowerCase()}` : '';

// Example 2
const realm = process.env.REALM;
const hasRealm = realm && ServiceClient.realms.includes(realm);
const subDomain = hasRealm ? `.${realm.toLowerCase()}` : '';
```

In the case of Example1, everything is fine. In the case of Example2, I get TS error `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.`.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript does some flow control analysis to narrow down types, but your example 2 isn't written in a way that would allow it. In your first case, you have this:

```
const subDomain = realm && ServiceClient.realms.includes(realm) ? `.${realm.toLowerCase()}` : '';
```

When this line starts running, `realm` might be undefined. Typescript analyses the code, and since that condition includes a check on `realm`, it deduces that every possible way of getting into `.${realm.toLowerCase()}` will have excluded `realm` from being undefined, and therefore its type has been narrowed.

But then there's a line like this:

```
const subDomain = hasRealm ? `.${realm.toLowerCase()}` : '';
```

When this line of code starts running, again `realm` might be undefined. But this time, the only check is of a boolean which, from typescript's perspective, is unrelated to `realm`. Depending on how `hasRealm` was produced, there are ways to get into `.${realm.toLowerCase()}` with realm still undefined. You know that's impossible because you're looking at the previous line, but typescript doesn't walk through the history of how hasRealm came to be and make deductions about other types based on that.

---

With regard to how to fix this, one option is to insist to typescript that you know the types better than it does, with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const realm = process.env.REALM;
const hasRealm = realm && ServiceClient.realms.includes(realm);
const subDomain = hasRealm ? `.${(realm as string).toLowerCase()}` : '';
```

Be aware that this removes some typesafety, because you're telling typescript to ignore what it has figured out and trust you instead. So if you made a mistake, it will trust in your mistake.

Another option is to rearrange the way you're doing things so that the lines don't begin with the value being unknown. For example, if the check is done in the condition of an `if` block, then typescript can narrow the types inside the block:

```
const realm = process.env.REALM;
let hasRealm, subDomain;
if (realm && ServiceClient.realms.includes(realm)) {
  hasRealm = true;
  subDomain = `.${realm.toLowerCase()}`
} else {
  hasRealm = false;
  subDomain = '';
}
```

It's more verbose, but safer in terms of types.

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense, thank you for the explanation. What's the fix for this then? If I do want to keep the two separated, i.e. use `hasRealm` in the next line, how should I make TS compile this?

Comment: @Kousha I've added in a couple options